# Use libCEC + USB dongle in Android app

Tags: android, hdmi, android-usb, hdmi-cec

My goal is to send HDMI CEC commands from a standard (i.e non-system) app running on an Android box equipped with Pulse-Eight's USB dongle.

Following [these instructions](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s426/sh/73529e1e-45b2-4bc5-a96a-3ec7d7f3dd3b/d95ec16f56bc05646417fb6c7cfbd702) I successfully managed to compile [libcec](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec) for Android and execute it as root on the box, with this command:

```
echo <my-cec-command> | cec-client -s /dev/ttyACM0
```

where `/dev/ttyACM0` is the device file created by the system when plugging the dongle.

However the permissions of this file prevent the command to be executed by a non-root user (therefore it cannot be executed from my Android app).

On the other hand the app can actually access the USB dongle via the [USB Host API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) of the Android SDK (provided the user grants the permission) and can even be wrapped into a USB serial controller with [UsbSerial](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial) library.

But I don't see any way to make the bridge between the connection provided by Android's USB Host API and libcec/cec-client. Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution that I have found so far is to use [USB Host API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) + [UsbSerial library](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial) to read/write CEC packets on the adapter's serial port with pure Java code (no embedded libCEC).

I did some retro-engineering on [libCEC](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec) to find out the appropriate commands for basic operations like switching TV on & off and setting active source.

And I finally came up with the following `UsbCecConnection` java class: https://gist.github.com/sdabet/ac4d7711d1a529806cb7b695530b1fac

Comment: I tried this approach but when I try to list all usb devices through usbManager.getDeviceList()  it returns no devices. Any idea why? I've made a post with my approaches but still with no success ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639210/use-libcec-usb-dongle-in-android-app ). Thanks in advance for any guidance.